# C++ How can I cast BYTE* to _CERT_TEMPLATE_EXT* and check result before further use?

Tags: c++, arrays, casting

My code is something like:

```
BYTE *byteVar;
_CERT_TEMPLATE_EXT *structVar;
// assign byteVar
structVar = (_CERT_TEMPLATE_EXT*)byteVar;
// Here I would like to check if in the byteVar there is a _CERT_TEMPLATE_EXT * or not; 
// (if the cast was successfull or not.)
```

I don't know what kind of cast I should use.

Comment: You cannot do that. A cast will always be performed and never fail (it's merely a compile time thing).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: `dynamic_cast` would like a word with you

Comment: What is `_CERT_TEMPLATE_EXT`? What is `BYTE`? What do you mean by "successful"? What is your definition of that criterion? When should the cast "fail"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not with intrinsic types like `BYTE` suggests.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: (a) "Suggests" being the operative word, and (b) you said "always". (c) Even a compile-time cast certainly can fail.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I am going to take a wild guess, and suggest [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377580(v=vs.85).aspx) is what `_CERT_TEMPLATE_EXT` is.  If I am right, `BYTE` will be a typedef for `unsigned char`. ... in which case @πάνταῥεῖ is pretty much right, and there is not a lot the OP can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to do crypto on Windows, and `_CERT_TEMPLATE_EXT` is as defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377580(v=vs.85).aspx), then there is no way you can reliably check.

You can look at `structVar->pszObjId`, and check if it looks like a valid OID.  If not, things have gone badly wrong with your application, and you need to debug it.  (If the pointer *wasn't* a `CERT_TEMPLATE_EXT`, the check will involve undefined behaviour - but so will using the converted value, so you are no worse off).

In general, you need `reinterpret_cast` to cast between unrelated pointer types, but at least GCC appears to allow just `static_cast` from `unsigned char *` (I don't have MSVC here to check readily.).  Personally, I think I would stick to a big scary `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: "You can look at structVar->pszObjId, and check if it looks like a valid OID" - This is clear in the debugger. But how can I check that in code? My next line of code is: if (strcmp(structVar->pszObjId, myString) == 0){// do smth.} and it crashes :(

Comment: The point is that you must arrange the code so that you don't do the cast unless the pointer *is* valid.  You will have to debug your code to find out why it isn't.

Comment: My code is looping through all extensions of a certificate, and needs to check a template string which is in the pszObjId. But I don't know if the extension is a template (_CERT_TEMPLATE_EXT). My c# hat is stuck well and I can't think c++. Can you give me another clue?